# Python os.path.join weird behaviour with ("any_path", "c:\") as input

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

So, I am making a pseudo login system and I've run into a few bugs with the os.path.join function.

It seems to act strangely when inputs such as "c:" or "d:" are input as the username, as it voids any path string before the root drives.

So, an input such as:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists( os.path.join( some_path, "this_is", "voided", "c:", "python34" ) )
True
```

Will have its first 3 statements completely ignored.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a known [bug](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

> On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path component (e.g., r'\foo') is encountered. If a component contains a drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

You can try [pathlib.PurePath.joinpath](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.joinpath)